# Subtracting data in one column based on values in another column

Tags: r

I want to subtract the values in the Temp column based on the values in the sensor column. Grouped by each date and location, I want to subtract Temp with the sensor value of 1 from Temp with a sensor value of 2. See data sample below.

```
date <- c("2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21","2016-03-21")
location <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
sensor <- c(1,16,1,16,1,16)
Temp <- c(35,34,45,42,46,47)
df <- data.frame(date,location,sensor,Temp)
```

This is my attempt at trying to do so using `dplyr`...

```
test <- df %>% group_by(date,location,sensor) %>% lfMaxTemp$Temp["sensor"==1]-lfMaxTemp$Temp["sensor"==16]
```

This is the result I would like:

```
        date location diff
1 2016-03-21        1    1
2 2016-03-21        2    3
3 2016-03-21        3   -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(date, location) %>% summarise(diff = Temp[sensor==1]- Temp[sensor==16])
#        date location  diff
#1 2016-03-21        1     1
#2 2016-03-21        2     3
#3 2016-03-21        3    -1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'date', 'location', `order` the rows based on 'sensor' in descending, and we summarise the output by the taking the difference between the 1st and 2nd observations with `diff`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-sensor), .(Diff  = diff(Temp)), .(date, location)]
#         date location Diff
#1: 2016-03-21        1    1
#2: 2016-03-21        2    3
#3: 2016-03-21        3   -1
```

NOTE: Here we assume that there are only 1 and 16 values in 'Temp' for each 'Temp'

In case, there are other values in 'Temp', just do a filter before the group by step

```
 setDT(df)[Temp %in% c(1, 16)][order(-sensor), .(Diff  = diff(Temp)), .(date, location)]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(date,location,sensor,Temp)
```

*Comments*

It is not recommended to use `as.data.frame(cbind(..` to construct the `data.frame` as it can result in all the columns to be in `class` `factor/character`.